# How do I add an URL field to the iOS Settings app (Like in Nike+)

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

There are several questions about this on StackOverflow, but they all claim this isn't possible, that you can only do this by showing a custom Settings page in your app. However, the [Nike+](https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/nike+-running/id387771637?mt=8) app does exactly what I want, as seen here:

[image]

So, again, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible with the current Settings.bundle for 3rd party apps. Checkout Apple docs [Settings Application Schema Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RootContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007018-SW1) for all available element types.

Comment: I just realized Nike+ is developed in cooperation with Apple which isseemingly why they can do stuff like this in the Settings.bundle. Meh.

Comment: nike playing by different rules in iOS than the rest of us developers ... what double standards Apple.

Comment: I think the appstore-app you linked (Nike+ Running) has nothing todo with Nike + iPod and it's settings.

Comment: @purplej0kr, you are correct, "Nike + iPod" is in Settings.app regardless.